# How to Use Filter Passed from Controller in Directive Link Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

I have a filter that i would like to use inside a directive.
I have a simple filter which works fine inside ng-repeat directive 
I am not quite sure how exactly I can apply inside directive link function.
I wrote below directive, taking the filter as a function, is this correct approach, how can i do it this way? or is there better way of doing it?

### JavaScript

```
myApp.directive('repeatDirective', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return {
        scope: {
            'filter': '&?',
            'itemList': '='
        },
        template: "<div ng-repeat='item in itemList'>{{item .name}}</div>",
        link: function (scope,element,attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
           **// how to  filter itemList here???**
        }
    };
}]);
```

### filter

```
$rootScope.collectionFilter= function (transType) {
if($scope.formData_EventDetails.actualPotential){
    if($scope.formData_EventDetails.actualPotential=='NM'){
        //console.log(transType.tranTypeName.indexOf('Near Miss'));

        return transType.tranTypeName.indexOf('Near Miss') >=0 ;
    }
    else{
        return transType.tranTypeName.indexOf('Near Miss') <0 ;
    }
}
return true;
};
```

### HTML

```
<repeat-directive item-list="someObjectCollection" filter="collectionFilter()">
</repeat-directive>
```

Comment: The best way to do it would be to define the filter in your app, then inject it into the directive and use it that way.  Then you can define it once as it's own entity and use it wherever it is needed

Answer (score 0):

Define your filter with Angular's register filter method, then use as you would use built-in filters. Let me know if you have questions.

Filter:

```
myApp.filter('collectionFilter', function(){
  return function(input){
    return input ? 'true : 'false';
  };
});
```

Comment: questions isn't about how to write a filter, its about how to use it inside a directive link function passed in as a function